# Finding the longest run of positive integers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Trying an OCaml question of iterating through the list and finding the longest run of positive or negative integers.  My thinking so far is you have to use List.fold_left and somehow +1 to the accumulator each time the next sign is the same as the current sign.  However, I'm a bit stuck on how to save that value.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think you should use List.fold_left here, it will just make your code less readable, a regular recursive function with accumulators would be better I think

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're being downvoted because this is the kind of basic question that's probably best answered by looking at an introduction to OCaml or functional programming in general.

The essential idea of folds in general and `List.fold_left` in particular is to maintain some state while traversing a collection (or a list in particular). When you say you want to "save" a value, the natural answer is that the value would be part of the state that you maintain while traversing the list.

The template for calling `List.fold_left` looks like this:

```
let final_state =
    List.fold_left update_function initial_state list
```

The update function takes the current state and the next element of the list, and returns the value of the next state. So it looks like this:

```
let update_function old_state list_element =
    let new_state =
        (* compute based on old state and element *)
    in
    new_state
```

So the explicit answer to your question is that your update function (the function that you "fold" over the list) would save a value by returning it as part of the new state.

Here's some code that returns the largest non-negative integer that it sees in a list:

```
let largest_int list =
    let update largest_so_far element =
        max largest_so_far element
    in
    List.fold_left update 0 list
```

This code "saves" the largest int seen so far by returning it as the value of the update function. (Note that it returns a value of 0 for an empty list.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah dang im also up all night doing OCaml LOL!!!
here's my shot at it ... one way is to sort the list and then find the first positive or first negative depending on how you sort ... checkout sort function from https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html ... then it's easy to get the size.

Let's say you don't want to use this built in library ... This code should be close to working (If my editor/debugger worked with OCaml I'd further test but I think this is close to good)

> ```
> let mostPositives(l: int list) : int list=
>
>    let counter = ref 0 in  
>    let maxSize = ref 0 in
>
>    for i = 0 to List.length(l) -1 do
>
>       if (List.nth l i) >= 0 then 
>         counter := !counter + 1
>       else 
>         counter := 1;
>
>       maxSize := (max !counter !maxSize );
>   done;
> ```